# Unchecked cast of generic typed method return in Java

Tags: java, generics

Apologies in advance, I'm struggling with how to word the Question Title and I know it's not ideal.

So I tried to implement my own little version of Java HashMap, and of course I want it to work for generics to allow it to work with any classes, as a real HashMap does.

In my `get(...)` method, I pass a key and want to return a value.  Everything works fine until I try to return something, then I get the commonly-asked-about `Xlint:unchecked` type-safety warning that my return value type can't be verified.  See the below snippet:

```
public <K, V> V get (K key) {
    if(!(key instanceof Object)) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: key given can't be guaranteed to have a hash function");
        return null;
    }
    int hashCode = key.hashCode();
    int index = hashCode % items.length;

    HashItem slot = items[index];
    while(slot != null) {
        if(slot.getKey().equals(key)) {
            V val = slot.getVal();
            return val;
        }
        slot = slot.getNext();
    }
    return null;
}
```

For reference, see the definition of `.getVal()`:

```
public V getVal() {
    return HashItem.this.val;
}
```

The `.getVal()` method is part of the private internal class `HashItem<K, V>`:

```
private class HashItem <K, V> {
    // blah blah
}
```

The home-made hash map class itself is structured like so:

```
public class MyHash <K, V>
{
    // blah blah

    private class HashItem <K, V> {
    // blah blah

        public V getVal() {
            return HashItem.this.val;
        }

        // blah blah
    }

    public MyHash (int capacity, double newLoadFactor) {
        // blah blah
    }

    // blah blah etc etc
}
```

Since `K` and `V` are constant throughout, I don't understand why the type of `.getVal()` is not guaranteed, or how to fix this.  I tried casting like so: `(V)` which works, but returns the *unchecked cast* error.  I also tried just returning the value but then I just get return type `Object` which is unacceptable.

How do I get my `.getVal()` method to return the proper type?

Comment: `get` should not be a generic method. The class should be generic, not the methods, so the `<K, V>` in `public <K, V> V get (K key)` just shouldn't be there.

Comment: I haven't taken a look at this code specifically, but a lot of collection-based classes -- especially those that use arrays, as a hash map does -- have unchecked warning exceptions due to type erasure. The warning doesn't mean you've done something wrong, just that the type system can't help you out; you should make sure it's right, and then suppress the warning using `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`. Separately: every class is a subclass of Object in Java, so you don't need to check `instanceof Object`.

Comment: `HashItem` also shouldn't have type parameters `<K, V>`, it should just use those from `MyHash`.

Comment: Also note that in the real `HashMap`, `get` accepts an `Object`, not a `K`. This may seem wrong at first, but it's really important to do it that way. If `get` and `containsKey` accept `K` rather than `Object` it makes it impossible to check that a `Map<? extends CharSequence, Object>` contains the key `"Foo"` because you can't pass a `String` to the `get` or `containsKey` method. `put`, on the other hand should accept a `K` and a `V`.

Answer (score 0):

1.change `public <K, V> V get(K key)` to `public V get(K key)`

2.change `HashItem slot = items[index];` to `HashItem<K, V> slot = items[index];`

sample code:

```
public class MyHash<K, V> {
    // blah blah

    private class HashItem<K, V> {
        // blah blah
        V val;
        K key;

        public V getVal() {
            return HashItem.this.val;
        }

        public K getKey() {
            return HashItem.this.key;
        }

        public HashItem<K, V> getNext() {
            return null;
        }

        // blah blah
    }

    HashItem<K, V>[] items;

    public V get(K key) {
        if (!(key instanceof Object)) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: key given can't be guaranteed to have a hash function");
            return null;
        }
        int hashCode = key.hashCode();
        int index = hashCode % items.length;

        HashItem<K, V> slot = items[index];
        while (slot != null) {
            if (slot.getKey().equals(key)) {
                V val = slot.getVal();
                return val;
            }
            slot = slot.getNext();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```